# how to build Boost 1.62.0 from Boost SCM Repositories tarball?

Tags: c++, boost

Because of firewall constraint I couldn't [download Boost directly](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.62.0/), 
alternatively, from [Boost SCM Repositories](http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/)  I clicked [Download GNU tarball](http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/?view=tar) and get the tarball. But then how could I build?

Last time when I use Boost there's a `Bootstrap.bat` which will build a `b2.exe`, then run `b2.exe`, the library will be built.

I couldn't find `Bootstrap.bat` or `b2.exe` after extracting from the tarball.

Comment: Wasn't it a little suspicious that the modification times of most of the files in that repository say things like "10 years"? You're trying to build boost [1.34.1](http://boost.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/boost/boost/boost/version.hpp?revision=1.15.2.2&view=markup)! Boost has been [hosted](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/ModularBoost) on [github](https://github.com/boostorg/boost) for a while now...

Comment: @DanMašek that's embarrassing! however, in https://github.com/boostorg/boost i clicked "Clone or Download" then "Download Zip", the files downloaded "boost-master.zip" doesn't contain any cpp file? does it mean i shall combine these two?

Comment: To be frank, I haven't tried getting boost from the repo myself. Perhaps the wiki page I linked in the previous comment has more details on how to fetch all the modules as well? If not, you could ask a new question specifically about this and just delete this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the git support for creating/downloading archives doesn't support submodules. So the archive from github will only contain the shell super-project files. You have three choices:

1. Complain to the git & github developers to have them add archive submodule support.
2. Complain to your IT network administrator to let you through the firewall.. Perhaps with a proxy set up.
3. Recursive clone the Boost git repo and read the general instruction on how to get a working setup from [here](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/wiki/Getting-Started).